# Did somewone has to migrate ftom vb6 to .net vbRightJustify (CellAlignment)?

Tags: .net, vb6

I have to migrate from vb6 to vb .net some code.
About vbRightJustify (member of AlignmentConstants) I have no clue about the .net equivalent for it.
Did anyone have?

error msg:

> 'vbRightJustify' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

```
grdTemp.CellAlignment = vbRightJustify
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcontentalignment?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
this.yourdgview.Columns["yourcolumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.Right;
```